# Unable to burn to DVD-ROM Discs

Tags: dvd, burning, brasero, k3b

I have a problem. The problem is that I could burn a data DVD before but now I can't. I've had Ubuntu 10.04, Ubuntu 10.10, and I have Ubuntu 11.10 right now. I've tried cleaning the DVD-ROM, and tried using other software (k3b, Gnome baker, NERO Linux 4), but I can't burn in any of them.

I have an Asus A6Jc and a LG HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-T40N disc drive.

**brasero-session.log:**

```
Checking session consistency (brasero_burn_check_session_consistency brasero-burn.c:1739)
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroBurnURI stopping
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroBurnURI no burn:// URI found
BraseroBurnURI stopping
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroLocalTrack stopping
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroLocalTrack no remote URIs
BraseroLocalTrack stopping
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_output_type
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroChecksumFiles stopping
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_output_type
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumFiles Adding graft for checksum file /.checksum.md5 file:///tmp/brasero_tmp_N5QM4V.md5
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_add_track
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumFiles Finished track successfully
BraseroChecksumFiles stopping
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibburn creating input
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibburn unsupported operation
BraseroLibburn deactivating
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage creating input
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroChecksumImage deactivating
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibisofs creating volume
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_data_label
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /.checksum.md5, URI = file:///tmp/brasero_tmp_N5QM4V.md5
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /the-middle-109-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi, URI = file:///media/Dufala/The%20Middle%20S01/the-middle-109-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /the-middle-114-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi, URI = file:///media/Dufala/The%20Middle%20S01/the-middle-114-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /the-middle-108-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi, URI = file:///media/Dufala/The%20Middle%20S01/the-middle-108-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /the-middle-112-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi, URI = file:///media/Dufala/The%20Middle%20S01/the-middle-112-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /the-middle-113-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi, URI = file:///media/Dufala/The%20Middle%20S01/the-middle-113-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /the-middle-107-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi, URI = file:///media/Dufala/The%20Middle%20S01/the-middle-107-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /the-middle-111-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi, URI = file:///media/Dufala/The%20Middle%20S01/the-middle-111-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /the-middle-106-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi, URI = file:///media/Dufala/The%20Middle%20S01/the-middle-106-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /the-middle-110-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi, URI = file:///media/Dufala/The%20Middle%20S01/the-middle-110-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /the-middle-124-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi, URI = file:///media/Dufala/The%20Middle%20S01/the-middle-124-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /the-middle-104-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi, URI = file:///media/Dufala/The%20Middle%20S01/the-middle-104-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /the-middle-105-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi, URI = file:///media/Dufala/The%20Middle%20S01/the-middle-105-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /the-middle-123-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi, URI = file:///media/Dufala/The%20Middle%20S01/the-middle-123-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /the-middle-118-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi, URI = file:///media/Dufala/The%20Middle%20S01/the-middle-118-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /the-middle-103-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi, URI = file:///media/Dufala/The%20Middle%20S01/the-middle-103-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /the-middle-117-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi, URI = file:///media/Dufala/The%20Middle%20S01/the-middle-117-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /the-middle-119-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi, URI = file:///media/Dufala/The%20Middle%20S01/the-middle-119-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /the-middle-102-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi, URI = file:///media/Dufala/The%20Middle%20S01/the-middle-102-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /the-middle-116-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi, URI = file:///media/Dufala/The%20Middle%20S01/the-middle-116-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /the-middle-121-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi, URI = file:///media/Dufala/The%20Middle%20S01/the-middle-121-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /the-middle-122-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi, URI = file:///media/Dufala/The%20Middle%20S01/the-middle-122-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /the-middle-101-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi, URI = file:///media/Dufala/The%20Middle%20S01/the-middle-101-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /the-middle-115-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi, URI = file:///media/Dufala/The%20Middle%20S01/the-middle-115-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /the-middle-120-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi, URI = file:///media/Dufala/The%20Middle%20S01/the-middle-120-dvdrip-xvid-cz-bedameda.avi
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibisofs Finished track successfully
BraseroLibisofs stopping
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibburn creating input
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_device
BraseroLibburn Drive (/dev/sr0) init result = 1
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_media
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_input_type
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn Setting multi 0
BraseroLibburn Setting burnproof 1
BraseroLibburn Setting dummy 0
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage linked to BraseroLibburn
BraseroChecksumImage creating input
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibisofs linked to BraseroChecksumImage
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_input_type
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroChecksumImage Starting checksum generation live (size = 0)
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_set_nonblocking
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_fd_out
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_fd_out
BraseroLibisofs Entering thread
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_fd_out
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_set_nonblocking
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_fd_out
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_fd_out
BraseroLibisofs Writing to pipe
BraseroLibburn burn_drive_convert_fs_adr( /dev/sr0 )
BraseroLibburn Writing
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_dangerous
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn burn_drive_is_enumerable_adr( /dev/sr0 ) is true
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn Async START UNIT succeeded after 0.1 seconds
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn mmc_set_streaming: end_lba=2298495 ,  r=4584 ,  w=11080
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn Allocating buffer via mmap()
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn dvd/bd Profile= 11h , obs= 32768 , obs_pad= 1
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn DVD pre-track 01 : get_nwa(0), ret= 1 , d->nwa= 0
BraseroLibburn Something went wrong
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_error
BraseroLibburn finished with an error
BraseroLibburn asked to stop because of an error
    error       = 15
    message = "Pri zápise na disk nastala chyba"  # Rough Translation: "When writing to disk error occurred"
BraseroLibisofs stopping
BraseroLibisofs Getting out thread
BraseroLibisofs disconnecting BraseroLibisofs from BraseroChecksumImage
BraseroChecksumImage stopping
BraseroChecksumImage disconnecting BraseroChecksumImage from BraseroLibburn
BraseroChecksumImage closing connection for BraseroChecksumImage
BraseroLibburn stopping
BraseroLibburn closing connection for BraseroLibburn
Session error : Pri zápise na disk nastala chyba (brasero_burn_record brasero-burn.c:2856)  #Rough Translation: "When writing to disk error occurred"
```

Comment: For future reference, you should not place your log files on sites like FileServe.com.  You're free to paste your logs to here, inside <pre> HTML tags.

Comment: @Dufala how is this coming for you? have you found a solution?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).